# SafeAreaView doesn't respect padding property in style

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Applying padding to SafeAreaView's style doesn't work. Example where padding does not make a difference:

```
<SafeAreaView style={[{ padding: 16}]}>
  <Text>
    Some content
  </Text>
</SafeAreaView>
```

How to fix the issue?

Answer (score 3):

SafeAreaView tag in React Native uses its own padding style prop to implement its behavior, overriding the one you pass to it. One of the approaches to deal with padding for `<SafeAreaView>` is to add a  `<View>` inside `<SafeAreaView>` and apply your padding there. An example is:

```
<SafeAreaView>
  <View style={[{ padding: 16}]}>
    <Text>
      Some content
    </Text>
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```